# Qual é a melhor arquitetura? Mysql multi BD ou single?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estamos atualmente trabalhando com um software web que esta indo pro mercado com uma grande aceitação. Ele recebe muitas interfaces de parceiros e gera muito conteúdo para cada tabela.
No passado optamos em criar um banco de dados para cada cliente, e um banco de dados centralizador e roteador de usuários, todos em Mysql. Mas hoje estou com gargalo de CPU e Memoria em um bom servidor, e estamos pendurando apenas 20 clientes.
Minha dúvida é se o modelo que adotamos no passado é o melhor, ou seja 1 BD para cada cliente que entrar (Mais ou menos 50 MB crescimento diário) ou se penduro tudo em apenas um banco de dados. 
Servidor Windows, Aplicação .net, BD Mysql

Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Edilson diante da situação exposta, levando em consideração que sua aplicação tem boa aceitação no mercado, no meu ponto de vista a melhor solução se tratando de arquitetura, é manter tudo em um único banco de dados, mas utilizar balanceamento de carga, uma sugestão seria utilizar por exemplo GCP (Google Cloud Plataform), que irá lhe oferecer um serviço bem robusto incluindo backup e escalabilidade automática.